# How to represent labialised velars and labials in Element Theory

Tags: phonology, generative-grammar

The contrast between velars and labials in Element Theory is represented either as, respectively, | | vs |U|, or |U| vs |U_| (headed |U|).

What if a language contrast plain velars and labials with labialised velars and labials, postalveolars and palatalised velars/palatals: /b bʷ d dʒ gʲ g gʷ/? How could these contrasts in Place of Articulation be represented in Element Theory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a distinction between head and dependent which is exploited, with C dominating head elements and adjoined V dominating dependent ones within the segment. See p. 10 of [van de Weijer](http://files.webklik.nl/user_files/2009_10/72522/Papers/Jeroen%20van%20de%20Weijer%20-%20Secondary%20and%20Double%20Articulation.pdf): replace "t" with "U" and you'd have a labialized labial. There is some variation in the theory as to representations e.g. whether velars are placeless.